# How are numbered lines of code in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run some bash script. I use crontab for that and errors are mailed to my mail. I get this error:

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 8: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

But, the line 8 is:
    TABLELIST="MyListOfTables"

I thought that the error is appearing due to MySQL... Am I wrong?
So maybe the "line 8" isn't just the 8th line of my script. Is there any rule for counting lines?

There is my script. Could you tell me what line is the "line 8"?

```
## some text
## some text
## some text
## some text
## some text

VAR1="something"
VAR2="something"       ....LINE 8??? 
VAR3="something"
VAR4="something"
VAR5="something"
VAR6="something"
VAR7="something"
VAR8="something"

# some text

# some text
mysql -D ${VAR4} -pPassword <<EOF
## some text

truncate table table_one;
truncate table table_two;
...
```

Comment: No, the line does not refer to the bash script but to the MySQL code itself. It is the line 8 of the MySQL query you are executing.

Comment: So I have to count only MySQL query lines? Without commented lines and without empty lines...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The here document  is a file literal or input stream literal: it is a section of a source code file that is treated as if it were a **separate file**. 
so any code included inside the here document is considered a separate file ,

In you script

```
# some text
# The here document starts here
mysql -D ${VAR4} -pPassword <<EOF #line 1 
## some text                      #line 2

truncate table table_one;
truncate table table_two;
...
EOF                               #line n
```

The line starting from `mysql -D ${VAR4} -pPassword <<EOF` to the endof here document (EOF) is executed as a separate file, The line 8 is the the 7th line from the statement `mysql -D ${VAR4} -pPassword <<EOF`

Comment: And an empty lines are counted too?

Comment: Fortunately, if I omit empty lines, the "line 8" is ##comment. And if I include empty lines, the "line 8" is empty line. How about comments? Are they counted?

Answer (score 0):

A search for "ERROR 1136" in addition to the word "Column" both hint strongly that the error is coming from MySQL rather than the shell. Have a look at the query which is terminated on the eighth line *after* the `mysql -D ${VAR4} -pPassword <<EOF` line.